# SAML and ticket cost

Tags: saml-2.0

We are implementing an IDM-service in the product I'm working with, and we can choose to use Radius or SAML 2.0 to communicate with the identity provider.

In the contract proposal, the supplier will give us Radius for free and charge approx 0.1 USD per requested ticket - is that reasonable? For me it seems extremely expensive.

From a solutions point of view we would like to use SAML, but the price says Radius...

Any out there who has any experience from that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an entirely political issue rather than a technical one.

Is the supplier using a third party Idp for strong authentication in the SAML option? In that case that third party might be the one charging the 0.1 USD.

In Sweden there are several companies that offer authentication of publicly approved electronic identities so that's my guess for why you did get that pricing.

From a technical point of view SAML2 is of course to prefer since it is a more modern standard.